# How can I change color of a button with internal link based on the URL in Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.6

First of all, I apologize for my bad English.

In one of my Joomla pages I have created a kind of menu with buttons that lead, each one of them, to an internal search page.

I'd like to get each of those buttons to change its color the moment it's on its respective url or page. I don't know if I am explaining myself correctly.

Theese are the html and css I have:

```
.d-flex.my-4 {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex}
.tile-button {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #d5d4d0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 15%;
    height: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'NGBold'}

.tile-button .tile-text a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 145px;
    height: 120px;
    justify-content: center}
.tile-button .icon {
    margin: 15px 0 20px;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #989794}
.tile-button:hover, .tile-button:focus, .tile-button.disabled {
    background: #677af60d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #677af6}
.tile-button:hover .icon, .tile-button:hover .tile-name, .tile-button:focus .icon, .tile-button:focus .tile-name, .tile-button.disabled .icon, .tile-button.disabled .tile-name {
    color: #677af6}


<div class="tile-button">
    <div class="tile-text"><a href="castings"><i class="fal fa-eye icon"></i><span class="tile-name">Todo</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="tile-button">
    <div class="tile-text"><a href="castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Teatro"><i class="fal fa-theater-masks icon"></i><span class="tile-name">Teatro</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="tile-button">
    <div class="tile-text"><a href="castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Largometraje"><i class="fal fa-camera-movie icon"></i><span class="tile-name">Cine</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="tile-button">
    <div class="tile-text"><a href="castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Serie%20de%20Televisión"><i class="fal fa-tv-retro icon"></i><span class="tile-name">Televisión</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="tile-button">
    <div class="tile-text"><a href="castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Locución"><i class="fal fa-microphone-alt icon"></i><span class="tile-name">Locución y Doblaje</span></a></div>
</div>

<div class="tile-button">
    <div class="tile-text"><a href="castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Spot%20de%20Televisión"><i class="fal fa-gem icon"></i><span class="tile-name">Publicidad</span></a></div>
</div>
```

I would like that when the visitor clicks on any of the buttons and visits the page of the (internal) link, the active button stays in the color of their choice.

I guess I need to do it with js, but I don't know the language.

This bellow is a screenshot of how the page and buttons are displayed. When the user clicks on one of these buttons, he is directed to the corresponding page. And all the buttons remain the same.

[image: This is how it is now]

What I'm looking for is that when the page corresponding to the button (for example, "theater") is opened, that specific button changes color, but only the button associated with the page, so that the user understands that it is there.

[image]

The specific page, to be able to see the buttons in operation, is this:

https://clandestinodeactores.com/castings

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

---

I'm trying to do this to include a class to each button depending to the url.

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname; 
    var activePage = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        activePage === '' ?  $('#allcasting').addClass("selected") : $('#allcasting').removeClass("selected") ;
        activePage === 'castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Teatro' ? $('#allteatro').addClass("selected") : $('#allteatro').removeClass("selected") ;
        activePage === 'castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Largometraje' ? $('#allcine').addClass("selected") : 
        $('#allcine').removeClass("selected") ; 
    activePage === 'castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Serie%20de%20Televisión' ? $('#alltele').addClass("selected") : $('#alltele').removeClass("selected") ;
    activePage === 'castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Locución' ? $('#alldoblaje').addClass("selected") : $('#alldoblaje').removeClass("selected") ;
    activePage === 'castings/buscar-por/tipo-de-produccion?value=Spot%20de%20Televisión' ? $('#allspots').addClass("selected") : $('#allspots').removeClass("selected") ;
    });
```

But it doesn't work how I'd expected.

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Maria.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.  Am I understand you correctly that the menu of buttons exists on ALL pages?  and that you want to indicate (by a specified colour) which of the buttons brought the user to that page?  Maybe can you [edit] your question to show a couple of screenshots and scribble on them to indicate your desired result?  My initial guess is that you should use php and css (if the destination page is a full page reload) to add an identifying class attribute which css will automatically colour.  I could use more clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mickmackusa, for your response. 

I just edited the post because, really, I think I didn't know how to express myself correctly. I'm going to take a closer look at everything you've written to see if it helps me make any progress. Thanks again.

Comment: Though not a solution for your coding attempt, I think you'll be happy to learn about `toggleClass()`. Give that a Google.  More importantly, why would you expect `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1` to contain a string with any slashes in it? That would be impossible.  If I'm not mistaken,  you want [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/2943403).  Use `console.log(activePage)` to show yourself what you are trying to match.